# Create shapefile with images as attributes using JavaScript

Tags: shapefile, javascript, geojson, export, geotag

I want to make a feature in a react.js web application where I can export/download shapefiles from the dashboard. I have implemented [shp-write](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shp-write) which takes a GeoJSON input. It is working fine with textual data. I would like to add 3 attributes which should contain an image in the shapefile. I have saved the required Image in my local storage. There is no JavaScript NPM module to do so

My implementation

```
var shpwrite = require('shp-write');
var options = {
    folder: 'myshapes',
    types: {
        point: 'mypoints',
        polygon: 'mypolygons',
        line: 'mylines'
    }
}
// a GeoJSON input for features
shpwrite.download({
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [
        {
            type: 'Feature',
            geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [0, 0]
            },
            properties: {
                name: 'Foo',
                image: 'C:\Users\DELL1\Downloads\Survey.png'
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'Feature',
            geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [0, 10]
            },
            properties: {
                name: 'Bar',
                image: 'C:\Users\DELL1\Downloads\Survey.png' 

            }
        }
    ]
}, options);
```

The Current output has image path as a text type field. It doesn't contain image. [image: Current result]

My Expected output should contain the image itself. [image: Expected output]

What approach can I use in JavaScript to achieve this result.

Comment: You may have a problem finding a library, for example GDAL doesn't support writing binary field types ~ https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html.  Wondering too, if you want to write a lot of images ,whether you'd hit an issue over shapefile size limit.  Perhaps writing to GeoPackage might be better option

Comment: Can you provide an example which shows working with exporting GeoPackage or shapefile(Ignoring shapefile size limit limitation) in javascript? Any source link will be a great help.

Comment: dBase III+ doesn't support inline binary data, just the memo field, which isn't supported by shapefiles. Including a path in a 254-character limited string field is the best you can do, format-wise. It still shouldn't be difficult to add an image tag to the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I would like to view the image in any GIS software like ArcGIS, Qgis instead of a webpage. And this shapefile needs to be distributed easily along with the images. I suppose adding the path in a string field won't work.